# Use custom creator and deleter for C structure

Tags: java, c, swig

I have on C side

```
typedef struct {} C_String;
C_String* StringNew();
void StringFree(C_String* string);
```

On Java I get such wrapper class

```
public class String {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected String(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(String obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        JNI.delete_C_String(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public String() {
    this(JNI.new_C_String(), true);
  }

}
```

JNI.new_С_String and JNI.delete_С_String are native methods generated by SWIG, they do simple work - allocate `C_String` by `malloc` and delete it by `free` respectively. In my case scenario should be different, since `C_String` is empty structure and acts like shortcut proper way should be allocation by `StringNew` which has `malloc` under hood and freeing by `StringFree`.

I want to use proper methods instead of `JNI.new_String`, `JNI.delete_String` what the easiest method to achieve this?

Comment: not sure I understand your question, but the official way to have Java and C talk to each other is called `JNI`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface - The `JNI` class that you seem to be using is (I think) unrelated.

Comment: Why isn't `JNI.new_String()` a proper method?

Comment: Yes, what's meant by "proper method" here? If what was meant is that you want that kind of syntax on the C side, it's unfortunately impossible as C lacks classes. The closest you have there is a struct with function pointers which is somewhat common for APIs (a table of function pointers), but I recommend just getting used to that `String*` style there with free-standing functions operating on an opaque handle/pointer.

Comment: What I mean by official way, is that JNI (see my link, not the JNI class used in the original question) is AFAIK the Oracle/Java endorsed way of exposing/interacting with Java objects from other languages (e.g. C). I don't know the JNI class used by the original poster, but that appears to be some third-party (hence unofficial) way.

Comment: @geert3 the JNI class referred to is just auto generated "official" JNI code from SWIG parsing the C headers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the C you showed is in a file called test.h the following SWIG interface would do what you wanted:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%extend C_String {
  C_String() {
    return StringNew();
  }
  ~C_String() {
    StringFree($self);
  }
}

%ignore StringNew;
%ignore StringFree;

%include "test.h"
```

This uses `%extend` to supply a custom constructor and destructor for the `C_String` type. This constructor/destructor pair just calls the C functions `StringNew` and `StringFree` respectively.

In your question you asked to have these calls happen from within the generated Java code. The way I've written it above makes these calls happen from within C instead. This has two primary benefits:

1. It is language neutral - the same interface file works equally well regardless of what language you're targeting.
2. It minimses calls between native and Java (or any other target) code. This is generally a good thing from a performance perspective since these cross-language jumps tend to be the most expensive part of your interface.

---

The remainder of this answer is mostly just here as a learning point and not a recommended solution.

If you really wanted to though you could write this as Java and make the JNI calls you asked for. To do this you would need to write a few [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_code_typemaps), you would need at least two which (untested) might look something like:

1. javabody:

   ```
   %typemap(javabody) C_String %{
     private long swigCPtr;
     protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

     protected $javaclassname(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
       swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
       swigCPtr = cPtr;
     }

     public $javaclassname() {
         $javaclassname tmp = $imclassname.StringNew();
         swigCMemOwn = tmp.swigCMemoryOwn;
         swigCPtr = tmp.swigCPtr;
         tmp.swigCMemoryOwn = false;
     }

     protected static long getCPtr($javaclassname obj) {
       return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
     }
   %}
   ```
2. javadestruct:

   ```
   %typemap(javabody) C_String %{
   public synchronized void delete() {
       if (swigCPtr != 0) {
         if (swigCMemOwn) {
           swigCMemOwn = false;
           $imclassname.StringFree(swigCPtr);
         }
         swigCPtr = 0;
       }
     }
   %}
   ```

But as noted previously this really isn't the best way to solve the problem. (You'd need a 'javadestruct_derived' typemap as well if you wanted this to still happen for cases with inheritance)